# The best way to serialize row JSON in Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have a database keeping key-value pairs. A key can be composite with dot as a separator (e.g. `https.stackoverflow.com`). I have to create JSON by these key-value pairs.
For instance, for the following pairs

```
https.stackoverflow.com 1
https.facebook.com 2
https.something.de 3
```

I want to get the follwing JSON and then send it a client using Spring Boot.

```
{
  "https" : [
    {
      "stackoverflow" : {
        "com" : "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "facebook" : {
        "com" : "2"
      }
    },
    {
      "something" : {
        "de" : "3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The question is what is the best practice to keep such objects in memory and how to send it to clients?

Firstly, I tried to manually create instance of JsonObject class provided by Gson but it has not implemented getters and can't be serialized by Jackson. Then I decided to create a map but there are some troubles with parametrization: a node can be of different types (Map, Array, String), which causes too many unchecked casts.

Comment: looks like you have a HashMap<String,ArrayList<Map<String,Map<String,String>>>> so you are gonna have to parse it like so if you want gson to convert it the JSON format you want

Comment: It's better not to go with implementation specific versions - sometimes you'll want a LinkedHashMap to preserve order.

Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>

If you're making a helper class for other JSON stuff, representing everything as a Map<String, Object> and nesting List<Object> and simple datatypes is also a good way to go.